# "Created at" text on Checkout Page

Tags: checkout

I am using Magento 2.3.3

I try to translate "Created at" text to my own languge but I could not.

I changed the

```
"Created At","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_Checkout 
"Created At","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_AdvancedCheckout 
"Created At","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_Sales 
"Created At","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_Braintree
```

but nothing change on checkout page yet
[image: chekout page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your translation with below lines

```
"Created at","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_Checkout here
"Created at","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_AdvancedCheckout 
"Created at","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_Sales here
"Created at","Oluşturulduğu Tarih",module,Magento_Braintree
```

Then run below command once

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f tr_TR
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Your english text is **"Created at"** not **"Created At"**. So just replace this.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I changed to uppercase "A" to lower case and run commands, but nothing is change.

Also " Created at" have in minicart as well

Comment: What is your locale ?

Comment: I working Turkish tr_TR

https://c4f4zqgreilsxxhy.mojostratus.io/tasarla-kapsonlu-sweatshirt

You can check from that product

Comment: **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f tr_TR** can you please run this command once and check ?

Comment: sorry,

same result

Comment: **pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/tr_TR/i18n/tr_TR.csv**

Go to this path and check your csv file and check translated string available there or not ?

Comment: Let me know if you want help here.

Comment: I think this is item come from my custom module, I try to edit

Comment: Okay then just add **"Created at","Oluşturulduğu Tarih"** this in your CSV instead of above 4 lines and then run setup upgrade once and check output in private window once

Answer (score 1):

Please use to add like this :

> "Created at","Oluşturulduğu Tarih"

OR

> "Created at:","Oluşturulduğu Tarih"

Don't forgot to clear cache.

Hope it will work.